# Customize jQuery Mobile Slider

Tags: jquery-mobile, custom-controls, slider

I'd like to customize the jQuery Mobile slider http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/slider/ so that I can keep track of the slider value (or percentage) and the number-input which shows the value, separately. (So that the number-input also can be 123.8%, while the slider is completely right.

I copied the code of the slider-plugin into a custom.js and named the widget "mobile.custom-slider", but in the code I can't find the input-type "number" anywhere. I also would like the text/number-input to be on the right side rather than on the left side.

Is there any good tutorial on how to create custom form elements in jQuery mobile? Is my approach with copy the original and change it the right one? Any ideas how to realize the above?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery Mobile docs themselves are probably your best bet for learning how to use them.  One of the best aspects of the JQuery based frameworks is the robust documentation.

If you have more specific questions, there are tons of JQuery slider questions on Stackoverflow.

Finally, check out the web JQuery UI docs, http://jqueryui.com/, many of the JQuery mobile classes are based off of this framework.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found a good tutorial in creating custom jQuery UI Plugins here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/coding-your-first-jquery-ui-plugin/